# routerLink not displaying the correct HTML even though the path is correct

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

This is my app-module file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AddFoodComponent } from './components/add-food/add-food.component';
import { EditClientComponent } from './components/edit-client/edit-client.component';
import { ClientInfoComponent } from './components/client-info/client-info.component';
import { ClientComponent } from './components/client/client.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './components/sidebar/sidebar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    EditClientComponent,
    ClientInfoComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ClientComponent,
    AddFoodComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(
      environment.firebaseConfig,
      'calorie-counter'
    ),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    FlashMessagesModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is my app-routing.module file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ClientInfoComponent } from './components/client-info/client-info.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { EditClientComponent } from './components/edit-client/edit-client.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { ClientComponent } from './components/client/client.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { AddFoodComponent } from './components/add-food/add-food.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'client', component: ClientComponent },
  { path: 'client/edit/:id', component: EditClientComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'navbar', component: NavbarComponent },
  { path: 'client/:id', component: ClientInfoComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'client/add', component: AddFoodComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**This is my component html that I am trying to display but it is not displaying, instead it is displaying another component's html**

This is the html that I want to generate when I run localhost:4200/client/add is the code below:

file: add-food-component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <a routerLink="/" class="btn btn-link">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></i> Back To Dashboard
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Add Client
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form #foodForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(foodForm)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="foodName">First Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          name="foodName"
          #fName="ngModel"
          [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': fName.errors && fName.touched }"
          [(ngModel)]="client.food"
          minlength="2"
          required
        />

        <div [hidden]="!fName.errors?.required" class="invalid-feedback">
          Food required
        </div>

        <div [hidden]="!fName.errors?.minlength" class="invalid-feedback">
          Must be at least 2 characters
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="calories">Calories</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          name="calories"
          #calories="ngModel"
          [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': calories.errors && calories.touched }"
          [(ngModel)]="client.calories"
          minlength="2"
          required
        />

        <div [hidden]="!calories.errors?.required" class="invalid-feedback">
          Last name required
        </div>

        <div [hidden]="!calories.errors?.minlength" class="invalid-feedback">
          Must be at least 2 characters
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

So for some reason its when I go to the route localhost:4200/client/add its displaying

"client-info works" which is the html component for client-info.component.html

**my routing is**

```
<a routerLink="/client/add" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
</a>
```

Any help is appreciated!!! Ive been stuck on this for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reordering your routes so that path:'client/add' is before the path:'client/:id' in your route list.

The Angular router processes the routes in order and takes the first match.  'client/add' could be interpreted as 'client/:id' where ':id' maps to 'add'.  So, it takes that as the first match in the list.

Per the [Angular Routing Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

> Route Order
>
> The order of routes is important because the Router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. List routes with a static path first, followed by an empty path route, which matches the default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL and the Router selects it only if no other routes match first.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much that worked!! Also thanks for linking the documentation.. I should read it more carefully..